# Getting Client ID of textbox in Gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

In order to use the 
`txtbox = document.getElementById()`function inside of an external javascript file, I am assigned the clientID of each control to a variable that I use.

So for instance, I say:

`var lbCancelID = '<%= lbCancel.ClientId %>';`

Then, when I call a function inside of an external javascript file that uses document.getElementById() it can do whatever it wants with the return element (txtbox).

This works perfectly fine until I got to an area where I needed to get a control in the gridviews edit template. Then, it told me the element didn't exist.

So I tried this: 
`var txtStartDateID = '<%#((GridViewRow)Container).FindControl("txtStartDate").ClientID %>'`

But get an error `'GridViewRow' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.` What can I do instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the method you have used in your markup will not work. 
In your code behind you can get the client id of your text box as

```
TextBox t = (TextBox) gridView.Rows[0].FindControl("TextBoxID"); // Give the index of the row. and gridview in your gridview ID
```

You can get the index from the selected index event. If you use above code in rowdatabound event then you can get the row index  by e.Row etc.